# TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable

Tags: django

I am trying to query database on the basis of multiple parameters, basically I fetch all the records from a table and then filter them out according to the parameters passed. Although the search portion works fine but when the resultant query set is returned, I get the following error:

TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable

I am not sure why that happens since I'm not trying to serialize anything.

My code looks something like:

view

```
class SearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'scand/search_result.html'
    context_object_name = 'images'

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = SearchForm(self.request.GET)
        query_dict = {}
        if form.is_valid():
            query_dict = form.cleaned_data
        self.request.session['query_dict'] = query_dict
        queryset = ImageTag.objects.search(query_dict)
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

model manager

```
class ImageTagManager(models.Manager):
    def ordered_images(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.order_by('id').all()
        return queryset

    def search(self, query_dict):

        if isinstance(query_dict, list):
            queryset = ImageTag.objects.filter(id__in=query_dict)
            if queryset is not None:
                return queryset
            else:
                return False

        # Initially getting all objects
        queryset_initial = ImageTag.objects.all()

        # copying queryset_initial to filter
        queryset = queryset_initial

        queryset = queryset.filter(company__iexact=query_dict['company']) if query_dict.get('company') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(accoff__iexact=query_dict['accoff']) if query_dict.get('accoff') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(section__iexact=query_dict['section']) if query_dict.get('section') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(docref__iexact=query_dict['docref']) if query_dict.get('docref') not in (
            None, '') else queryset

        start_date = query_dict.get('start_date')
        end_date = query_dict.get('end_date')

        if start_date not in (None, '') and end_date not in (None, '') and start_date < end_date:
            queryset = queryset.filter(start_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
        elif start_date not in (None, ''):
            queryset = queryset.filter(start_date__exact=start_date) if query_dict.get('docref') not in (
                None, '') else queryset

        queryset = queryset.filter(pagenum__iexact=query_dict['pagenum']) if query_dict.get('pagenum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(refnum__iexact=query_dict['refnum']) if query_dict.get('refnum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(pernum__iexact=query_dict['pernum']) if query_dict.get('pernum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr1__iexact=query_dict['attr1']) if query_dict.get('attr1') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr2__iexact=query_dict['attr2']) if query_dict.get('attr2') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr3__iexact=query_dict['attr3']) if query_dict.get('attr3') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr4__iexact=query_dict['attr4']) if query_dict.get('attr4') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr5__iexact=query_dict['attr5']) if query_dict.get('attr5') not in (
            None, '') else queryset

        if len(query_dict.get('tags')) > 0:
            tags = query_dict['tags']
            queryset = queryset.filter(tags__name__in=[tags])

        if queryset != queryset_initial:
            return queryset
        else:
            return []
```

error

```
Internal Server Error: /search/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 58, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 70, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 96, in encode
    serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\scandoc\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 87, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable
[06/Feb/2019 16:25:20] "GET /search/?company=&accoff=&section=&docref=&start_date_month=3&start_date_day=6&start_date_year=1983&end_date_month=10&end_date_day=6&end_date_year=2007&pagenum=&refnum=&pernum=&attr1=&attr2=&attr3=&attr4=&attr5=&tags= HTTP/1.1" 500 109487
```

Also, this is how I am filtering the records, if someone has a better way of doing it, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serialization error seems to be happening because you're trying to store the `query_dict` in session:

```
self.request.session['query_dict'] = query_dict
```

The `query_dict` contains date objects which are not JSON serializable and by default Django [will serialize session data using JSON](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization).

To resolve, you should convert the date objects in the `query_dict` into something which is JSON serializable (e.g. a timestamp) before you store the data in session.

Alternatively you could switch to using the [PickleSerializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer) which would allow you to store the date objects. Set the [`SESSION_SERIALIZER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-serializer) variable in your `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

Note that there is a vulnerability with the `PickleSerializer` if you're using the cookie backend. However, you seem to be using the database backend so that should be less of an issue.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Do you have any suggestions the way I'm filtering the queryset? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Majid glad to help. Yes I think there is a way you could simplify the filtering of the queryset and reduce the amount of boilerplate. One way would be to iterate the dictionary and call `query.filter()` with a dynamic argument based on the current dictionary key. It would be best to raise a separate question on SO to address that.

Comment: I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54567423/6915030

Answer (score 0):

Is there are `DateField` in your model?

```
TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable
```

Django converts data to json in view. And This error is raied when `json.dumps` tried to convert `date` object.

```
>>> datetime.date(2018, 12, 1)
>>> json.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jos/Projects/sandbox/py-sand/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-1a41a0b88650>", line 1, in <module>
    json.dumps(d)
  File "/home/jos/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/home/jos/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/jos/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/jos/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable
```

So you must use `serializer` for change your data to json. See [django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/).