# Django - Reducing the boilerplate for to filter the queryset and possibly improve performance

Tags: django

I am using Model Manager to return a filtered search queryset but currently the boilerplate for that is quite long, I'd be glad if I could find a way to reduce the boilerplate as well as gain some performance.

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
class ImageTagManager(models.Manager):
    def ordered_images(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.order_by('id').all()
        return queryset

    def search(self, query_dict):

        if isinstance(query_dict, list):
            queryset = ImageTag.objects.filter(id__in=query_dict)
            if queryset is not None:
                return queryset
            else:
                return False

        # Initially getting all objects
        queryset_initial = ImageTag.objects.all()

        # copying queryset_initial to filter
        queryset = queryset_initial

        queryset = queryset.filter(company__iexact=query_dict['company']) if query_dict.get('company') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(accoff__iexact=query_dict['accoff']) if query_dict.get('accoff') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(section__iexact=query_dict['section']) if query_dict.get('section') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(docref__iexact=query_dict['docref']) if query_dict.get('docref') not in (
            None, '') else queryset

        start_date = query_dict.get('start_date')
        end_date = query_dict.get('end_date')

        if start_date not in (None, '') and end_date not in (None, '') and start_date < end_date:
            queryset = queryset.filter(start_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
        elif start_date not in (None, ''):
            queryset = queryset.filter(start_date__exact=start_date) if query_dict.get('docref') not in (
                None, '') else queryset

        queryset = queryset.filter(pagenum__iexact=query_dict['pagenum']) if query_dict.get('pagenum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(refnum__iexact=query_dict['refnum']) if query_dict.get('refnum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(pernum__iexact=query_dict['pernum']) if query_dict.get('pernum') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr1__iexact=query_dict['attr1']) if query_dict.get('attr1') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr2__iexact=query_dict['attr2']) if query_dict.get('attr2') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr3__iexact=query_dict['attr3']) if query_dict.get('attr3') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr4__iexact=query_dict['attr4']) if query_dict.get('attr4') not in (
            None, '') else queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(attr5__iexact=query_dict['attr5']) if query_dict.get('attr5') not in (
            None, '') else queryset

        if len(query_dict.get('tags')) > 0:
            tags = query_dict['tags']
            queryset = queryset.filter(tags__name__in=[tags])

        if queryset != queryset_initial:
            return queryset
        else:
            return []
```

Basically what the search does is it first grabs all the records and then filters it down according to the search criteria passed through query_dict (Form). The resultant queryset is returned.

Comment: You are hitting database multiple times and in `ImageTag.objects.all().filter()` using 'all' is redundant you can do `ImageTag.objects.filter` you dont need to grab all then filter you can directly apply filter. you can cut down lot of code here

Comment: all() is necessary to get a queryset if the search criteria dict is empty. it doesn't affect the resulting SQL query at all. Also, did you measure the number of database queries this code generates? It should be 0 (zero). What you are doing is constructing a query which won't hit the database until you do something with the final queryset.

Comment: Performing the actual query should be several orders of magnitude more expensive than constructing it, so the performance aspect should be negligible (unless you've measured otherwise). What you could do is simplify the code creating the filtered queryset by looping through the criteria rather than spelling them out one by one. But wouldn't this question be better off over at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I have just measured the number of database queries and it is 0. And yes, I'm using all() in order to know whether the search query is empty. I tried to loop through the criteria but I couldn't achieve what I wanted, perhaps I didn't do it the right way and only after that I tried this approach. as for Code Review SE, I didn't know about it, should I repeat the question over there?

Answer (score 0):

In light of @Endre Both's comment I managed to do a loop through the filter criteria, I found a little difficulty handling the list criteria and handled it separately, the way I did it is:

```
    def search(self, query_dict):

        searched_for = {}
        for key in query_dict:
            if query_dict[key] not in (None, ''):
                if isinstance(query_dict[key], list):
                    pass
                else:
                    searched_for[key] = query_dict[key]
                # print(key)

        # Initially getting all objects
        queryset_initial = ImageTag.objects.all()

        # filtering based on non list criteria
        queryset = queryset_initial.filter(**searched_for)

        # filtering based on list criteria
        if query_dict['tags'] not in (None, ''):
            if len(query_dict['tags']) > 0:
                queryset.filter(tags__name__in=query_dict['tags'])

        if queryset != queryset_initial:
            return queryset
        else:
            return []
```

If someone has even better way of doing it, I'd really appreciate if shared.